# Cannot access my box admin page

Tags: router, administrator, isp

I have a problem with my ISP, I had a box installed at home but my ISP blocked access to the admin page via a browser using the gateway which is `192.168.1.254` so for every manipulation like the modification of password or other stuffs, I have to call their technicians.

So I tried to check the open ports on the box to see if there is an open web port since the technicians manage to access an admin page but I did not find anything. All I have found is that the box ports 80 and 23, 443 are all filtered and only port `49152/tcp` is open. By typing `192.168.1.254:49152`, it just displays a text saying `404 Not Found`.

Does anyone know how to access the admin page of this kind of box or tell me if it's not possible?

Comment: Don't. Consider the box as part of the ISP network. In consultation with rhem, put your own router behind it (or replace it) and get your ISP to reconfigure it to pass all inbound traffic to your router - there are multiple ways of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You access it from the WAN port not the LAN port - simple but effective security*. This is just a simple extension of the common in-house method of disabling admin over WiFi to prevent fly-by attacks.
There will also be a log/pass known only to the ISP.

I'm afraid you're stuck with it, or looking for a better ISP.

As a long shot you could ask them if it will switch to 'pure modem' mode so you can put your own router in instead.

*If you try that yourself, it won't have an established, known-range DHCP address, so you won't bypass it that way either.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your ISP having access to your passwords doesn't sound very trustworthy (there are huge security issues here), I would find a different one as soon as possible (in Germany, for all I know, this would be illegal as soon as it comes to your home network).

I would second [Tetsujin suggestion](https://superuser.com/a/1594304/201818), to try to set up your own modem/router.

If this doesn't work, I would check your contract to see if manipulation of the router settings for your actually is forbidden. If it's not you should find the make and model of your router an check on-line if there is a way to get in. Again: check your contract **FIRST** (and consult a lawyer if you are not sure), I can not stress this enough. Also be aware that **you will be liable** for any damage done.

The router might not have a HTML admin page at all in addition to the measures Tetsujin mentioned. But this is all speculation anyway, just trying different ports most likely won't help you much, you'll have to take a wider structured approach.